# Meet at Wolfram Technology Conference?

Tags: discussion

I am curious who all is currently attending the Wolfram Technology Conference in Champaign.  Would love to put a face with a name for the people I have learned from on SE.  Perhaps a meet up?  Or feel free to come introduce yourself.

-Ben Kickert

Comment: Got a chance to meet up with Kuba and RCollins.  Thanks for the connection fellas!

Comment: I enjoyed meeting several folks at the networking dinner tonight.  Thanks for taking the time to introduce yourselves.  Looking forward to keeping up the communication! -bk

Comment: Post pics if you can. ;)

Comment: I didn't even think to take pictures, but I know some of the guys did.  Hopefully we can get them posted.

Comment: I have been live tweeting things at www.twitter.com/datavelopment but it is mostly general WTC stuff...

Comment: ahem, that would be rcollyer, you met. :)

Comment: @rcollyer  That's even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### place update

That room is already taken but I will wait on a way to catch you and once gathered we will find a place

#### time updated

I am trying to schedule a meeting. **5:30pm** today, the meetup room in Homewood Suites, a hotel next to the conference hotel.
If anyone is around, please come :)

Comment: It is hard to catch everyone at once but I will try to gather pictures with as many of them as possible.

Comment: You could maybe encourage the ones who are members here to post their own stuff, too. :)

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less wait, you're encouraging us to take effort and participate? How rude. :)

Comment: Besides the grainy picture I posted in chat, all the pictures I took were of presentation slides.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

From left to right @Edmund, @Kuba, @PFonseca and @Zviovich. The young lad in the middle got the second prize in the one-liner competition, prodded by Pedro and Diego.
[image]

@Zviovich, @P.Fonseca, @JasonB, @Kuba at the Big Grove Tavern.

[image]
And of course, the traditional picture (with @Antonov in the back row.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the grainy picture, it is just from the webcam on my computer.

Here we have @Fred Klingener, @User21, @Zviovich, Mark Fisher, @Kuba, @bcolletti, and @kickert

[image]

Comment: Damn, I am suspiciously absent in all these photos!!! (But here the most...)

Comment: You are backrowing the third picture that @Zviovich posted above.  And, if you look really closely in the background of the keynote picture, you are sitting at my table leaning back just below the midpoint of the left screen.

Comment: Ok, all the guys in the picture don‘t need an avatar any more. ... and talking of and about guys: There needs to be a quota! :-)

Comment: @gwr, yeah diversity wasn't the strong point of the Wolfram Tech Conference.  There was actually a question from the floor about it at the Key Note Dinner.